# Adding Class files to Google App Engine Wave Bot in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-wave

Yeah quite a specific question. I'm making a bot for Google Wave and I'm a bit confused.

I have some Java class files of a separate package I want to implement. I put them in the lib directory but they're not found by Wave when its uploaded.

Eclipse compiles them fine, as it has the directory, but I guess it doesn't upload it to appspot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Wave contacting the server at all? If so, the problem isn't Wave-specific, it's AppEngine-specific - so you don't need to worry much about the Wave documentation, just [AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html).

How have you packaged the class files? Are they just "loose" or have you bundled them into a jar file?

What error are you getting, exactly?

Have you tried following the [Wave tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/java-tutorial.html) to build the Parroty application? Did that work? If so, that's a good starting point for adding your own classes.

Comment: The class files are loose, but they have a package.

I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Try putting them in a jar file then, like the other libraries there.